# Changing Quote Status to Won

Tags: process-builder, quote, status

How can I change the field status of a Quote to "Won" if the customer approves of the quote? I am only seeing a predefined picklist of values that does not include "Won". What is the best way to achieve this through the Process Builder?

Comment: You can add the picklist values on your status field